# Finding sum of series upto n terms .

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the series :

$1 \cdot k^1 + 2 \cdot k^2 + 3 \cdot k^3 + \dots + n \cdot k^n$

how can one find the sum for this series?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean$1\cdot{k^1}+2\cdot{k^2}+...+n\cdot{k^n}$?

Comment: @hkmather802  yes , i mean the same .

Comment: is k a constant?

Comment: @hkmather802   yes it is .

Comment: You can try to first prove that (for $k\neq 1$) $$\sum_{i=1}^n k^i=\frac{k (k^n-1)}{k-1} $$ with for instance induction. Then you can use the following trick: $$\sum_{i=1}^n nk^n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{d}{dk} k^{n+1}-\sum_{i=1} k^n=\frac{d}{dk} \left (\sum_{i=1}^n k^{n+1}\right)-\sum_{i=1} k^n$$ in combination with the earlier derived formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x \neq 1$, then
$1+x+x^2+\cdots+ x^n = {1 -x^{n+1} \over 1-x}$. Now differentiate both sides.

The left will be $1+2x+\cdots+n x^{n-1}$. Compute the right side by differentiating. Then multiply by $x$ to get the final result.